Sit or Sit Down? Have a Seat And Be Seated? Are Any of Them Rude?
Without any deep searches, I think that using the phrase "Have a seat" seems formal and the contact feels being respected. I feel the same for "Be seated" if I'm not wrong.
"Sit down" means the same and it's not meant to be for either respect or insult. But according to the situation in some scenes of the movies, I thought maybe using "sit" itself without adding "down" when using it alone as an imperative verb is a kind of insult.
Since they use "sit" for telling animals like dog to sit, I thought maybe this could be counted as another proof for what I thought.

There are subtle differences in meaning: "be seated" usually implies you have a seat and should return to it; "take a seat" means you should find a chair and sit on it. So a lot of the difference is in meaning, not politeness. Although I associate "be seated" with church, so maybe it is a bit more formal?

Have a seat is the most formal, but it isn't necessarily the most friendly or polite. If somebody were standing, and said "Hello. Have a seat." without making any motion to sit down themself, that could be seen as commanding or insulting, just as sit down would in that situation. Likewise, "Everybody, be seated" sounds commanding.
We often soften a command with "please", "won't you?/why don't you?", by making it a mutual action/question, or simply with tone.
sit (or have a seat, or be seated) used with any of the above sounds friendly, not rude:


Please, sit!
Won't you sit?
Let's sit!/Shall we sit?
(Happily, excitedly) Sit! Sit!



Please, sit! could sound pretty curt. Just remove the exclamation mark.
